# MVC3 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, xmlignore

I'm working on an MVC3 application.
I created my POCO classes through the ADO.NET DbContext Generator and 
I'm using partial classes to add validation on properties.
Now, when I try to serialize one of my entities I receive this error:

> "Cannot serialize member .... of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[....."

I googled this error and I discovered that it's possible to add the tag 
`[XmlIgnore]` to certain properties.
But the point is that I can't put this tag on the properties because they are
created everytime by the generator.
So how I can do this in a simpler way ?

Answer (score 1):

The key is the [`MetadataTypeAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute.aspx). You can add this to your partial class which implements the additional properties and your validation logic. Then create a meta data class with a property of the same name of your generated class, and apply the attribute you need.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(MyPOCOMetaData))]
public partial class MyPOCO
{
    // your partial validation code and properties
}

public class MyPOCOMetaData
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string GenerateProperyName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I do this but it doesn't work
  [MetadataType(typeof(Cliente_Validation))]
    public partial class Cliente
    {
       

    }
  
    public class Cliente_Validation
    {
  [XmlIgnore]
        public virtual ICollection<Iscrizione> Iscrizioni { get; set; }
        [XmlIgnore]
        public virtual ICollection<Vendita> Vendite { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Does it work if you remove `virtual`from the meta data class property? I can't imagine that XmlSerializer ignores the meta data type.

Comment: i tried this too,  but it doesn't work...[MetadataType(typeof(Cliente_Validation))] public partial class Cliente { } public class Cliente_Validation { [XmlIgnore] public virtual ICollection<Iscrizione> Iscrizioni { get; set; } [XmlIgnore] public virtual ICollection<Vendita> Vendite { get; set; } }